# Calculate mean of data frame by row

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

Is there a way to calculate the mean of a row from a data frame?

So for example:

```
df <- data.frame(X = c(1,1,1,1,2,2), Y = c(1,4,4,4,4,3), Z = c(2,5,6,8,3,1))

df
  X Y Z
1 1 1 2
2 1 4 5
3 1 4 6
4 1 4 8
5 2 4 3
6 2 3 1
```

So how can I calculate the mean per row?

```
mean(df[,1:3])
```

I really don't understand why this won't work, I mean the same code works for example for `min()` or `max()` but not for `mean()`.

```
min(df[,1:3])

[1] 1
```

Comment: `rowMeans(df[,1:3])` or `apply(df[,1:3],1, mean)`

Comment: Okay thanks, this works. But what is the reason that mean() behaves differently than min() or max()

Comment: You are mistaken, neither min or max is working okay, they are suppose to be returning single value only, but your ask is to return rowwise, you need to use pmin or pmax to get row wise values. Read more about vectorized functions in R, mean/sum/min/max , all these will return single value unless applied with some functionals or loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `df[,1:3]` you are choosing all rows of `df` and columns `1:3`. When you apply `min` or `max` to that, it simply looks for the `min/max` among all numbers. It is not doing it by `row`.

So when yo try to apply the same logic to `mean`, it again finds the `mean` value among all numbers in all three columns. Again, not by `row`.

You need to `apply` a function to a dimension of `df`. For this, use `apply(df, 1, mean)` as *PKumar* suggested. If you need the `mean` for each column, you say `apply(df, 2, mean)`. To learn more about `apply` type `?apply` on the R console.

`rowMeans` and `colMeans` are shortcuts for `apply`.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to use apply function
you can compute the mean of all the rows by using the following syntax

```
apply(df,1, mean)
[1] 1.333333 3.333333 3.666667 4.333333 3.000000 2.000000
```

#when the second argument is 1, you are computing mean for each row, if it is set to 2 then you are computing for each column

To compute the mean of a specific row you need to subset the row
use the following code

```
> apply(df[4,],1, mean) #here you compute the mean of the 4th row
#output
       4 
4.333333
```